# Непонятные ссылки в Google Webmasters

Tags: hosting, http-status-code-404, virustotal, google-webmasters

Есть несколько сайтов, расположенных на разных хостингах. Сайты используют разные CMS (WordPress, ModX).

В Google Webmasters постоянно появляются ссылки с ошибкой 404. Часто урл содержит текст `NONOrot` или `NONOroh`. Сайты проверял на вирусы, используя скрипт AI-Bolit. Вирусы нашлись на паре сайтов, а ссылки появляются на всех.

Есть предложения куда копать?

Скриншоты из Google Webmasters:

[image: Скриншот1]

---

[image: Скриншот2]

Answer (score 0):

Когда у вас был вирус на сайте, созданные им страницы были проиндексированы Google, потому и показываются в webmasters. Если вы уверены, что на сайте сейчас вирусов нет, запросите повторное сканирование страниц роботом Google, инструкция [здесь](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=ru).

На сайты WordPress поставьте плагин [WordFence Security](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) и проведите первое сканирование вручную. WordFence на сегодняшний день - лучший, пожалуй, антивирус и файервол для WordPress.

Comment: Один из сайтов http://potolky24.by/
Просканировал плагином WordFence Security. Обнаружены только не обновленные плагины(Исправил). Ссылки остались.
https://prnt.sc/gt1ety

Comment: Google webmasters не может реагировать на изменения на вашем сайте онлайн. Запустите повторное сканирование (отправьте файл Sitemap). На странице Сканирование->файлы sitemap можете увидеть сообщение типа "Этот файл Файл индекса Sitemap был отправлен 13 июля 2017 г. и обработан 8 окт. 2017 г." - да, а вы как думали? Вам сейчас остается только отправить sitemap и ждать